# Where can i find a simple filterbank BP/wavelet filter function, in C#/JS?

Tags: audio, filter, signal-processing, wavelet

I am searching for a filter function which inputs an audio signal (a float[]) and returns the amplitude of the audio signal at a given frequency, i.e.:

```
void WAVELET (float In , float Freq ):float
{
    out = in * coefficients*a1*b1*c1*d1/Freq;
    return in;
}

void MAKE_SPECTROGRAM2D(float[] stream)
{
   for (var bands = 0, bands < 1024 , bands++)

       for (var i = 0, i < AudioStream.Length , i++)

           var spectrogram2D[i,j] = WAVELET(AudioStream[i] , bands*22050/1024)

}
```

I have found some wavelet transformation projects (i.e. [1](https://waveletstudio.codeplex.com/) and [2](https://wavelets.codeplex.com/)). It's very confusing trying to understand the codes. Wavelets seem to be much different to audio filters. A kind of bandpass filter for audio analysis would be fine. I can only find collections of difficult functions that have matrix transformations and seem to be not destined to input an array of data. I haven't managed to find filterbank audio filter functions online. i am simply confused, some information would be very helpful.

Comment: A spectrogram is typically done by using an FFT, which is a complex matrix transform, so you will have to learn to convert (window) your array of data into the proper format.

Comment: Thanks. filterbanks use FIR filters that are intrinsically 1D array algorythms and so dont have any of the window constraints in T/F range as matrix Time/Freq transforms, cohen transforms and FFT. Because it is simply a bank of parallel filters, i seek code for a singe FIR filter adapted to analysing audio bands. Debauchies wavelet is a short FIR filter for example, but i haven't found it formatted as FIR code.

Comment: FIR filters have nearly identical time frequency constraints as windowed FFTs of roughly similar length.  Which should explain one method to create one or more FIR filters.